# axios sending post request to backend node server, but response is coming back empty. How can I troubleshoot and fix this issue?

Tags: express, post, axios, cors, mern

I am working on a MERN application. I am using axios to send post request to backend node server. The problem is that its working just fine in my desktop but in android when I open the site i am getting a error.

While debugging I found that actually the response from node server is coming to be empty. In fact through logging i found the request is not at all processed at node server. I think there something wrong with how I am using axios or it might just be some cors error. It might also be the error related to sending post to server from host other than the local machine where node server is running.

Here is the code for axios post:

```
import axios from "axios";
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (res) => {
    console.log("here1");
    return { status: res.status, ...res.data };
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log("in error", error);
    return {
      status: error.response.status,
      message: error.response.data.message,
    };
  }
);

const nodeURL = "http://localhost:5000";

export const postToNodeServer = async (route, body) => {
  console.log("in post");
  const res = await axios.post(nodeURL + route, body, {
    withCredentials: true,
  });
  return res;
};
```

and the backend code:

```
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));

//posts
app.post("/register", register);
app.post("/login", login);
```

error screenshots:

[[image: network tab ss]]

[[image: post request details]]

Comment: Did you try removing the `origin: "http://localhost:3000"` ? It might be causing the issue by only letting that origin to access the endpoint

Comment: actually i am using passport js for authentication. For allowing credentials(cookies) to backend i need both origin and credential options otherwise i am getting cors error.